# Ads api: request only those creatives that are currently used

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ads, facebook-ads-api

When using Facebook's Ads API, I'd like to request all creatives for an account that are currently being used by an adgroup. I.e. where the count_current_adgroups value is > 0. I can pull all creatives for the account with:

">https://graph.facebook.com/adcreatives/?ids=act_123456789&access_token=

How do you limit this request to only return adcreatives that are being used by an adgroup?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John - This functionality doesn't currently exist.  Your best bet is to load all the active adgroups in your account like this:

https://graph.facebook.com/adaccount/adgroups

Inside of each adgroup, it will list the adcreative that is currently associated with that adgroup.  Collect all of these adcreative IDs together, and deduplicate them,  then load them all using this syntax:

https://graph.facebook.com/adaccount/adcreatives?ids=1,2,3,4

This should give you the functionality you need, although it will take two calls to the Facebook Ads API to compute what you want.

Comment: Thanks again Justin. We're doing it slightly differently in that we pull all adcreatives for the account and filter out those that aren't found in the active adgroups list we pull. The first implementation was as you suggest but we got worried about building too long of a GET request. At 13 characters per ID, pulling a couple hundred adcreatives leads to a very long parameter string.

Comment: Just saw that FB now allows pulling creatives by adgroup and/or campaign: "Pro tip: It is now possible to get all of the ad creatives for an ad campaign or adgroup by the following method:
/<campaign_id>/adcreatives
/<adgroup_id>/adcreatives
The docs have been updated with these new connections."